# PHP double quotes

Tags: php, printing, double-quotes

I have this code:

```
<?php

$attribute = 'name';
$value = 'John';

print_r("$attribute$value");
```

it outputs:

```
nameJohn
```

I want to keep using "" (double quotes) to output:

```
name_value: John
```

I tried:

```
print_r("$attribute_value: $value");
```

But of course it doesn't work (there is no variable $attribute_value).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use curly braces to indicate what is a variable and what is a string:

```
print_r("{$attribute}_value: $value");
```

You can also use `printf()` to format your string (or sprintf()` if you wish to capture it to a variable):

```
printf("%s_value: %s", $attribute, $value);
```

Comment: Or... `print_r($attribute . "_value: " . $value);`

Comment: @John Conde - it works, I'll mark your answer as answer in 10 min (it doesn't allow now:)

Comment: @Condorcho, I insisted on using double quotes.

Comment: May I ask why you want (or need) to use double quotes?

Comment: Because I just want to know how to use them. Because people are curious. And I am human:)

Answer (score 0):

Assign 'name_value' to $attribute.

```
<?php

$attribute = 'name_value';
$value = 'John';

print_r("$attribute: $value");
```

exp: https://3v4l.org/QBepr

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Did not see that as a requirement in the OP.